# How can I provide default values for Phoenix simple_form / .input field?

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I could not find any examples in the documentation for simple_form on how to provide a default value.
Here on line 33 I tried to hard code it, but that didn't work.
I'm using Phoenix 1.7.6

```
 25       <.simple_form
 26         for={@form}
 27         id="weight-form"
 28         phx-target={@myself}
 29         phx-change="validate"
 30         phx-submit="save"
 31       >
 32         <.input field={@form[:weight]} type="number" label="Weight" step="any" />
 33         <.input field={@form[:date]} type="date" label="Date" step="any" value="01.05.1982" />
 34         <:actions>
 35           <.button phx-disable-with="Saving...">Save Weight</.button>
 36         </:actions>
 37       </.simple_form>
 40     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the format you've used for that string. Not sure where you got that from but [the format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#date_strings) is basically ISO8601, ie. `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
... value="1982-05-01"
```

You can also provide an elixir date in `{}`s if that's simpler:

```
... value={~D[1982-05-01]}
```